# pug pretty option - new line after 'a' tag in HTML output

Tags: html, pug

I'm using pug via gulp with the `{pretty: true}` option. It's fine with `div`/`header`/`section`/`nav` tags, but when I use `a` or `span`, it is compiled without space between the tags.

```
nav.header__menu
    a(class="header__menu__link" href="#") About
    a(class="header__menu__link" href="#") Home
```

Compiling to

```
<nav class="header__menu"><a class="header__menu__link" href="#">About</a><a class="header__menu__link" href="#">Home</a></nav>
```

I want

```
<nav class="header__menu">
   <a class="header__menu__link" href="#">About</a>
   <a class="header__menu__link" href="#">Home</a>
</nav>
```

And yes, **='\n'** doesn't help in this task, because it is pushing the tag to a new line from absolute beginning, and therefore destroying the tree formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why Pug does that, is that `a` elements are *inline* elements. Contrary to *block* elements (such as `div`s), *inline* elements wrap on the page, and thus also (by convention) in the HTML code. I do not know of a way to tell Pug to do this differently, but I would suggest wrapping the `a` elements in `li` elements. That would preserve the newlines, but also adhere to convention:

Generally, whenever you are listing items (such as links), it is common practice to use `ul`s (unordered lists). Especially in navigation elements, listing a number of anchor tags. (If you don't like the bullet points that are placed in front of elements automatically, you can change that easily with some CSS.)